# How to push elements on array in a promise then methods

Tags: node.js, promise

I'm trying to put element in an array that have been define externaly a method.

```
let result = JSON.parse(body);
let objects = [];
result.results.forEach(element => {
    getObjectDetail(element.place_id).then((detail) => {
        console.log(detail);
        let object = {
            place_id: element.place_id,
            name: element.name,
            rating: element.rating,
            address: detail.result.formatted_address,
            photo:
                   googleApiHost +
                   googlePlacePrefix +
                   googlePlacesPlaceImageUri +
                   '?key=' +
                   googleApiKey +
                   '&maxwidth=400&photoreference=' +
                   element.photos[0].photo_reference,
                   website: detail.result.website
         }
         console.log(object);
         objects.push(object);
     });
});
console.log(objects);
```

`console.log(object)` give me the good result with all fields setted.
But `console.log(objects)` return an empty array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the whole idea of promise- it operates asynchronously and executes the `.then` clause when it is resolved. But meanwhile, the main code flow continues to execute.

Effectively this means that in your case, the flow goes like this: 
enter forEach loop > initialize a seperate promise for each element > log(objects) > execute the `.then` clause for every promise resolved.

So the logging executes before any promise is resolved and any item is pushed to objects.
Your best bet here is to use `Promise.all`, which operates on array of promises and returns a resolved promise when **all** of the promises are resolved, or a rejected promise whenever **one** promise is rejected.

```
let result = JSON.parse(body);
let objects = [];
let objectsPromises = [];
result.results.forEach( (element, index) => {
    objectsPromises[index] = getObjectDetail(element.place_id);
});
Promise.all(objectsPromises).then( (values) => {
   // The "values" is an array containing all the values of the resolved promises.
   // You can now iterate over it and perform the code in your `.then` clause for each 
   //promise, and then manipulate the objects array, as this iteration is synchronous 
   // (operates on actual values and not promises)
}
console.log(objects); // NOTE: THIS WILL STILL LOG EMPTY ARRAY!
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use for of loop better than for each, because the forEach loop contains a callback and try using async await it makes the code more readable.

```
const func = async ()=> { 
    let result = JSON.parse(body);
    let objects = [];
    for (var element of result.results) {
    var detail = await getObjectDetail(element.place_id);
        console.log(detail);
        let object = {
            place_id: element.place_id,
            name: element.name,
            rating: element.rating,
            address: detail.result.formatted_address,
            photo: googleApiHost +
                    googlePlacePrefix +
                    googlePlacesPlaceImageUri +
                    '?key=' +
                    googleApiKey +
                    '&maxwidth=400&photoreference=' +
                    element.photos[0].photo_reference,
                    website: detail.result.website
            }
        console.log(object);
        objects.push(object);
    }
}

console.log(objects);
```

Comment: I haven't tried this cause the first answer works, but it seems to be a good solution. Thanks